# ASP.Net Dynamic Data or MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compare, dynamic-data

I've been working with web-forms and I want to switch to the MVC pattern based on some facts and other goodies that I see in it. I was going good with MVC review when I came across the latest Dynamic Data (which in past was called Dynamic Data Templates).

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe in backend both MVC2 & DD use the MVC pattern but then DD supports server-side controls and has a lot of automation using its latest scaffolding technique. We can make a running website with-in a few hours and DD handles most of it for us.

MS people day it is 'massively' flexible and configurable. However, as I went on looking for online resources I was disappointed (compared to the solutions available in MVC) a recent post from the asp.net forum hit me hard -

> Re: Why I won't be using Dynamic Data
> any more - please read this Microsoft!
>
> http://forums.asp.net/t/1604037.aspx?PageIndex=2ums.asp.net/t/1604037.aspx?PageIndex=2

And it looks like a non-MS guy has done more in DD then the actual team!
His website has some complex solutions - http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/

---

*So, are MVC2 & DD actually two different things or how similar are they? Besides, a major concern I thought about DD is that it generates everything at runtime - doesn't that make it slow and less performance conscious compared to MVC?*

> Below, I've attached some of my
> screens which I've accomplished in
> Web-forms (I need to be able to plug
> such features in my web-app). For
> example, Grid-cascading, optimized
> pagination, header-filters, frozen
> grid-header, bulk edit, etc...grid-header, bulk edit, etc...

Please share your experience whether its wise to wait until DD matures and has enough documentation and solutions or is MVC anytime better?

Some Screens:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The screenshot looks like half-backed jqGrid to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe in backend both MVC2 & DD use the MVC

Yeah, thats wrong.  DD is "ball of mud" pattern.

> So, are MVC2 & DD actually two
>   different things or how similar are
>   they?

They are completely separate, do almost nothing the same and only share a common language and framework.

> Please share your experience whether its wise to wait until DD matures and has enough >documentation and solutions or is MVC anytime better?

This is very localized to you and your project.  I will use immature projects if they solve a need for personal projects but at work I'm willing to wait for stability.